# Toggle visibility of input fields based on the selected option in Alpine JS

Tags: javascript, laravel, alpine.js

I have a select option fields and I want to toggle the visibility of some input fields based on the selected option. I got to know that `@click` event doesn't work on `<option>` so is there a way to achieve this using `@change` on `<select>` or any other way.

```php
<div class="py-1" x-show="!open" x-transition>
    <span class="px-1 text-sm text-gray-600">Gender</span>
    <select @change="alert($el.value)" wire:model="gender">
        <option>Select Gender</option>
        <option value="male">Male</option>
        <option value="female">Female</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Curretnly I implemented this on a radio button like this

```php
<div class="form-check">
    <input class="form-check-input appearance-none rounded-full h-4 w-4 border border-gray-300 bg-white checked:bg-[#60D619] checked:border-[#60D619] focus:outline-none transition duration-200 mt-1 align-top bg-no-repeat bg-center bg-contain float-left mr-2 cursor-pointer" type="radio" id="figurativeMarkWithWords" wire:model="tradeMarkType" @click="isFigurativeMark = true; isWordMark = true" value="figurativeMarkWithWords">
    <label class="form-check-label inline-block px-1 text-sm text-gray-600" for="figurativeMarkWithWords">
        Figurative Mark containing words
    </label>
</div>
```

Now I want to transform this into a selection.

Answer (score 2):

You can bind the x-show to the selected value in the dropdown like this. No need to listen for a change event.

```
<div x-data="{ country: '' }">
    <div x-show="country == 'US'" x-cloak>
        Show this when US is selected in dropdown.
    </div>
    <div x-show="country != 'US' && country != ''" x-cloak>
        Show this when another country is selected in dropdown.
    </div>

    <div>
        <label>Country*</label>
        <select id="country" x-model="country">
            <option>Choose a country</option>
            <option value="US">USA</option>
            <option value="CA">Canada</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```